# Filter register from two tables

Tags: mysql, sql

I am new here and with PHP/MySQL programming. I need do the next consult in my database.

I have two tables:

-The first of relations between users where friends have the value "2"
The columns is like:

```
id  |  Username1  |  username2  |  relation
```

-The seconds is for messages post by users
The columns is like:

```
id  |  username  |  message
```

The id is the "primary key" with auto increment property. (in both)

I want to show all message of friends of one user by order of post (Most recently first)

So I need select the max value id where the user1 and user2 is friends, but I need select the max value of "messages table" and check if they are friends in the "relations table"

I know what the next is not the syntax but I need something like this:

```
  SELECT message
    FROM message_table
   WHERE MAX(id) AND (  FROM relations
                       WHERE (   (   user1="randomuser" 
                                  OR user2="randomuser") 
                              AND relation="2")
                     )
ORDER BY id DESC
```

I know what that is wrong... but I need that two filters to show all friend message in posting order.. So how can I show register from one table with a one condition in that table and the second condition in other table.

Edit: Example:

```
id  |  Username1  |  username2  |  relation
1      Randomuser1   Randomuser2     2
2      Randomuser1   Randomuser3     0
3      Randomuser1   Randomuser5     2

id  |  Username  |  message  
1      Randomuser1   Hi this is a random message?    
2      Randomuser2   I don"t like your message    
3      Randomuser5   Sure, is a bad message
```

So I want to show all message of friends of randomuser1 by order of posting

First the user"s friends of Randomuser1  is
Randomuser2 and Randomuser5 (The "2" Mean they are friends)
so i want to show all messages of their friends by order of posting (By id order of second table (message_table))

So i need a output like:

```
id  |  Username  |  message  
3      Randomuser5   Sure, is a bad message
2      Randomuser2   I don"t like your message
```

That is the output what I need when I choose the messages of friends of user Randomuser1

Comment: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d41d8 
plz add your table data here

Comment: As u finish your schema then let me know coz we don't know wat data you are having it in your schema

Comment: I'm not sure I understood your question: do you want to get all messages from all friends of a user? Or just the last message?

Comment: I need show a N quantity of messages order by id (posting- mayor to minor) And the user of consult and the owner of the message are friends (i think N can be around 30-25 But no  all of one friend user, i need 30 order by id mayor to minor and have the condition of they are friends)

Comment: Sorry  user3426968 i cant understand how works that online tool... is for recreate the own database?